# Elasticsearch : es.index() changes the Mapping when message is pushed

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, kibana-4, elasticsearch-mapping

I am trying to push some messages like this to elasticsearch

```
id=1
list=asd,bcv mnmn,kjkj, pop asd dgf
```

so, each message has an `id` field which is a string, and a `list` field that contains a list of string values

when i push this into elastic and try to create charts in kibana, the default analyzer kicks in and splits my `list` by the space character. Hence it breaks up my values. I tried to create a mapping for my index as

```
mapping='''
{ 
"test":
    { 
  "properties": {
        "DocumentID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Tags":{
            "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
}'''

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': server, 'port': port}])
indexName = "testindex"    
es.indices.create(index=indexName, body=mapping)
```

so this should create the index with the mapping i defined. Now , i push the messages by simply

```
es.index(indexName, docType, messageBody)
```

but even now, Kibana breaks up my values! why was the mapping not applied ?

and when i do

```
GET /testindex/_mapping/test
```

i get

```
{
  "testindex": {
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "properties": {
          "DocumentID": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "Tags": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

why did the mapping change? How can i specify the mapping type when i do

```
es.index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. You need to provide the root `mappings` object while creating the index and you dont need it when using `_mapping` end point and that is the reason `put_mapping` worked and `create` did not. You can see that in [api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/indices-put-mapping.html).

```
mapping = ''' 
{
    "mappings": {
        "test": {
            "properties": {
                "DocumentID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Tags": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'''
```

Now this will work as expected

```
es.indices.create(index=indexName, body=mapping)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

i was able to get the correct mapping to work by

```
es.indices.create(index=indexName)
es.indices.put_mapping(docType, mapping, indexName)
```

i dont understand why

```
es.indices.create(index=indexName, body=mapping)
```

did not work. this should have worked as per the API.